# Data doesn't updated but create a new line in database

Tags: html, sql

I have a form looks like this:

[image: question]

So when I click the edit button the name apperas at the text-area. When I edit it and click the green button, it should update the data in the database and refresh it. But it creates a new line and also keeps the one which was edited.

Here are the part of the code, which should be wrong:

Input:

```
  <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $brand_value; ?>">
```

Button:

```
  <input type="submit" name="add_submit" value="Nyomtató <?php echo (isset($_GET['edit'])?'szerkesztése':'hozzáadása'); ?>" class="btn btn-success">
```

SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO nyomtatok (nyomtato_neve) VALUES ('$brand')";
if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
  $sql = "UPDATE nyomtatok SET nyomtato_neve = '$brand' WHERE id = '$edit_id'";
}
$db->query($sql);
header('Location: nyomtatok.php');
```

If theese parts of code are not enough please let me know and I will show you the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You execute insert before check if is and edit or a new

you should perform insert in alternative of update

```
  if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE nyomtatok SET nyomtato_neve = '$brand' WHERE id = '$edit_id'";
  } esle {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO nyomtatok (nyomtato_neve) VALUES ('$brand')";
  }
  $db->query($sql);
  header('Location: nyomtatok.php');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help unfortunately.